# Make sense of plotting a transition matrix

Tags: self-study, markov-process, transition-matrix

I'm studying statistics and I'm trying to understand markov chain topic. I'm using the package "markovchain" in R to obtain the stationary distribution.

From this transition matrix $M$:

```
  A    B
A 0.97 0.03
B 0.05 0.95
```

using the "steadyStates" function I get this:

```
A     B
0.625 0.375
```

After a few try a noticed that I can obtain the same result if I do this: M^200

So, what I did was to compute 200 matrices using powers from 1 to 200 to show how each element in the matrix changes after every iteration (e.g. how 0.97 becomes 0.625 and 0.03 becomes 0.375). Then I plotted these 4 vectors (with 200 entries each) in 4 separate plots (I'm attaching the two types of plot I got here below).

My questions are:

Does it makes any sense to plot these values?

Can I get some insight from them? For example, can I interpret these plots like some sort of a "elbow method"? Or maybe something like: *after 50 iteration I have a good approximation of the final values...*

If I use two or more matrices can I say: *matrix one "converges" before matrix two, three, etc.?*

Thank you for your time.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you noticed these are *perfect* exponential plots?  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/191730 for a sketch of the underlying theory.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I honestly don't understand a lot of that reference but I guess I did something like plotting x, x^2, x^3, etc...